# iPhone Minimum Hit Area Height for Table Cell

Tags: ios

I have a table view in my app in which there is a section where there are 4 clickable and 4 non-clickable cells (in random order). It is a small part of the larger table which has different types of cells, and is relatively unimportant but necessary nonetheless.

In order to allow scrolling past it more quickly since it's rarely used I have made the cell height be 32px, however this is lower than Apple's suggestion of 44x44px minimum touch area. Is there an exception for table cells like this that aren't of great importance or are they strict on the rule and I should bump it back to 44px height just in case?

Comment: You could just try if all people can use it on an iPhone 5 or an iPad Mini. Can they tap where they want to tap? Including big men with big fingers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the 44px is not a requirement just a guideline.  The answer to this is purely subjective.  You can go smaller but you are trading ease of use for it.  Run some experiments and see what UI experience you are willing to tolerate. (keep in mind the variety of devices your app will be used on and the different sized hands out there)

Comment: The cells are attributes for/about the item being viewed, and their main function is to show those attribute values. Clicking them goes to a list page with items filtered by their value, but it's very much a secondary function. Thanks for the response though, after hearing some other opinions as well I think I'll try with 36px and hope for the best.